# drupal_render() and formBuilder's getForm

Tags: 8

What exactly is the best way to accomplish this? I can pass the `$form` object returned from `getForm` to `drupal_render()` and get the correct themed output fragment but the API docs say this function will be deprecated in D9 and to use the renderer service instead.

When I use:

```
\Drupal::service('renderer')->render($form)
```

I get

> You have requested a non-existent service "renderer". Did you mean one of these: "render_html_renderer", "html_fragment_renderer",
>   "html_page_renderer"?

When I use:

```
\Drupal::service('render_html_renderer')->render($form)
```

I get a valid object with a protected `content()` method, which contains the string, but I can't seem to find any valid public functions to access this.

I can normally use the route builder to point to a form controller that I've created but, in this instance, I just want to pull an existing form, get the HTML content, and display it - hopefully as a variable in a preprocess function. I don't necessarily want to create a block, since I probably won't be reusing it.

What is the best way to do this? Keep using `drupal_render()` until D9? Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Aha! Devel is appearently quite useful these days as I spotted a available methods tab within and found the `getContent()` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are almost no reasons to manually call drupal_render(), you can use/return render arrays almost anywhere, controllers, blocks and also in twig templates.

If you do `$variables['form'] = $your_form;`in preprocess, then `{{ form }}` in your template should just work.

Answer (score 0):

I think should work if you do something like

```
$form = \Drupal::service('render_html_renderer')->render($form);
print $form->__toString();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using [`renderRoot()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Renderer.php/function/Renderer%3A%3ArenderRoot/8.4.x) instead of [`render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Renderer.php/function/Renderer%3A%3Arender/8.4.x), e.g.

```
\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($form)
```

> Renders final HTML given a structured array tree.